# Generate uniform random variable when lower boundary is close to zero

Tags: r, random, boundary, uniform-distribution

When I run in R 
 `runif(100,max=0.1, min=1e-10)`
 
 I get 100 uniformly distributed random variables **between 0.1 and 0.0001**. So, there is no random value between 0.0001 and the min value (`min=1e-10`). 
How to generate uniform random variables on the whole interval (between min and max values)?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'random variable'?

Comment: realization of a random variable

Comment: your last round of edits seems odd to me ... "values" is plural, not singular ... and your last sentence is a question ... but whatever ...

Comment: I had an intention to accept your corrections but I am not familiar with this website, so somehow I dismissed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Edited to replace `exp(-10)` with `1e-10`*)

Given your max of `0.1` and min of `1e-10`, the probability that any given value is less than `1e-4` is given by

```
(1e-4 - 1e-10) / (0.1 - 1e-10) = 9.99999e-04
```

The probability that 100 random values from this distribution are all greater than `1e-4` is

```
(1 - 9.99999e-04) ^ 100 = 0.90479
```

About 90.5%. So you shouldn't be at all surprised that in a draw of 100 numbers from this distribution, you didn't see any less than `1e-4`. This is expected more than 90.5% of the time theoretically. We can even verify this in simulation:

```
set.seed(47) # for replicability
# 100,000 times, draw 100 numbers from your uniform distribution
d = replicate(n = 1e5, runif(100, max = 0.1, min = 1e-10))
# what proportion of the 100k draws have no values less than 1e-4?
mean(colSums(d < 1e-4) == 0)
# [1] 0.90557
# 90.56% - very close to our calculated 90.48%
```

For more precision, we can repeat with even more replications

```
# same thing, 1 million replications
d2 = replicate(n = 1e6, runif(100, max = 0.1, min = 1e-10))
mean(colSums(d2 < 1e-4) == 0)
# [1] 0.90481
```

So, with 1MM replications, `runif()` is almost exactly meeting expectations. It is off from the expectation by `0.90481 - 0.90479 = 0.00002`. I would say there is absolutely no evidence that `runif` is broken.

We can even plot the histograms for some of the replications. Here are the first 20:

```
par(mfrow = c(4, 5), mar = rep(0.4, 4))
for (i in 1:20) {
    hist(d[, i], main = "", xlab  = "", axes = F, 
         col = "gray70", border = "gray40")
}
```

[image: Looks pretty uniform]

The histograms are showing 10 bars each, so each bar is about `.01` wide (since the total range is about 0.1). The range you are interested in is about `0.0001` wide. To see that in a histogram, we would need to plot 1,000 bars per plot, 100 times as many bars. Using 1,000 bins doesn't make a lot of sense when there are only 100 values. Of course almost all the bins will be empty, and the lowest one, in particular, will be empty about 90% of the time as we calculated above.

To get more very low random values, your two choices are (a) draw more numbers from the uniform or (b) change distributions to one that has more weight closer to 0. You could try an exponential distribution? Or maybe, if you want a hard upper bound as well you could scale a beta distribution? Your other choice is to not use random values at all, maybe you want evenly spaced values and `seq` is what you're looking for?

Comment: The min value is 0.0000000001 or something like that (and not exp(-10) as I wrote). Sorry for that.
But I need uniform distribution that covers entire interval. It seams to me that R has some limitations that I do not how to overcome.

Comment: Unless you edit your question to show it, we're not convinced there's a limitation in R. There may be limitations in floating point arithmetic for small numbers since the distribution of possible numbers becomes non-uniform, but that shouldn't be happening at 1e-10.

Comment: beautiful small-multiple plot. May I recommend `col="gray"` in your `hist()` calls ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the recommendation :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you aren't generating enough to make it likely enough that you've seen one:

```
> range(runif(100,max=0.1,min=exp(-10)))
[1] 0.00199544 0.09938462
> range(runif(1000,max=0.1,min=exp(-10)))
[1] 0.0002407759 0.0999674631
> range(runif(10000,max=0.1,min=exp(-10)))
[1] 5.428209e-05 9.998912e-02
```

How often do they occur?

```
> sum(runif(10000,max=0.1,min=exp(-10)) < .0001)
[1] 5
```

5 in that sample of 10000. So the chances of getting one in a sample of 100 is... (Actually you can work this out exactly from the number and the properties of a Uniform distribution).

Comment: Run runif(200,max=0.1, min=exp(-10)) and I get very good distributed values between 0.000451 and 0.09921. I made 15 chunks between these two values where each chunk contains between 10 and 15 of these generated values. And there is 0 values less than 0.000451. So, the half of my min-max interval is not covered with these data, while the other half is very good filled. 

 I will get some less values if I generate $1e^{6}$ random variables but... there is no uniform distribution for the whole interval.

Comment: "*half of my min-max interval is not covered*" this flat-out wrong. Your scale goes from `exp(-10) = 4.5e-5` to `0.1`, a total interval width of `0.0999546`. Your observed values go from `0.000451` to `0.09921`, an observed range of `0.098759`. Taking the ratio of observed to total width, you have 98.8% coverage of your interval!! Do you instead want random values that are uniformly distributed *on a log scale*?

Comment: My bad in typing. The min value is 0.0000000001 or something like that (and not exp(-10) as I wrote). Sorry for that. I didn't copy->paste the R code (which I should probably do).

Comment: That doesn't change the point, just the details - you are looking at a **tiny sliver** of the interval - using `1e-10` as the minimum the total interval width is `0.1 - 1e-10 = 0.099999999`, which we can approximate to `0.1`. You're focusing on a slice of width `1e-4 - 1e-10`, which is about `1e-4`, which is about 0.1% of the interval. It's like you're randomly dialing phone numbers and you are surprised that the people who answer aren't people you know! Aren't phone numbers evenly distributed? Surely by the 10th try you would have found a relative or at least a friend... Right? No.

Comment: I'm exaggerating the odds in the phone number example, but if you want a high chance of random draws in 0.1% of your interval, you will need to draw many more than 100 values.